# Unhandled promise rejection in node.js while using mongooseSchema.pre('save') method

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, bcrypt

```
//This is the user model
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const saltRounds = 10;
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    index: {
      unique: true
    }
  },
  password: {
    type: String
  }
});

userSchema.pre("save", function(next) {
  var user = this;
  if (!user.isModified("password")) {
    return next();
  }

  bcrypt.genSalt(saltRounds, function(err, salt) {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, salt, function(err, hashedPassword) {
      if (err) {
        return next(err)
      }
      user.password = hashedPassword;
      next();
    });
  });
});

userSchema.methods.checkPassword = function(guess, cb) {
  bcrypt.compare(guess, this.password, function(err, isMatch) {
    cb(err, isMatch);
  });
};
const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
module.exports = User;


//The code below  is the /signup route
router.post('/signup', (req, res) => {
  User.findOne({
    email: req.body.email
  }, (err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }

    if (user) {
      // handle case for user already exists!!
      res.json({
        success: false,
        message: 'An account with this email already exists'
      });
    } else {
      var newUser = new User({
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password
      });

      newUser.save((err) => {
        if (err) {
          return res.send(err);
        }
        let jwtData = {
          email: req.body.email
        };

        let token = jwt.sign(jwtData, jwtSecret);

        res.json({
          success: true,
          token: token
        });
      });
    }
  });
});
```

when I make a post request to /signup route I got this error in nodejs version 8.1.2:

(node:8317) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: cb must be a function or
null to return a Promise

The route works fine if I remove the mongoose pre method.
But I want to hash the passwords.Please help me on this issue.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your pre-save callback takes a function called 'done' but you are calling 'next' instead.

It should be:

```
userSchema.pre("save", function(next) {
    ...
}
```